# Adding custom attributes to product list

Tags: product-list, product-attribute

I'm very confused with a small issue in my catalog/product/list.phtml file.

i'm trying to add the Manufacturer attribute that comes with Magento to my grid listing and have added the following code.

```
<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer') ?>
<?php if( $_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer') ): ?>
    <p class="manufacturer">Manufactured by:<br/><?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer')?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Now this is the same code I've used on my product/view.phtml page and it works there. But this doesn't work at all, the echo by its self or using it in the if statement. Both return nothing.

So I have to do something special to get these attributes on the list.phtml file?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Make sure the attribute `manufacturer` (and others that you want to list) have the flag `Use in product listing` set to `Yes`. After setting the flag you should rebuild your product flat index if `Flat catalog` is enabled.

Comment: Damn, right yes that makes sense. I did not include it because it's being called somewhere custom no the view.phtml template. I'll have to override the product listing row in view.phtml to exclude it manually the. Thanks.