# Get the short description for homepage below the products?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, design

I have a design where I need to insert three lines of the product description in home page of the product and beside the price value I need to include a title name called has "Price". Please check the below image.

[image]

Now my layout seems to be like this

[image]

This is my .phtml file which fetches the products

```
<?php
    $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    ?>
    <?php if(!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
    <p class="note-msg"><?php echo $this->__('There are no products matching the           selection.') ?></p>
    <?php else: ?>
    <div class="category-products">

    <?php // List mode ?>
    <?php if($this->getMode()!='grid'): ?>
    <?php $_iterator = 0; ?>
    <ol class="products-list" id="products-list">
    <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
        <li class="item<?php if( ++$_iterator == sizeof($_productCollection) ): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
            <?php // Product Image ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">
                <?php /* Based on the native RWD styling, product images are displayed at a max of ~400px wide when viewed on a
                        one column page layout with four product columns from a 1280px viewport. For bandwidth reasons,
                        we are going to serve a 300px image, as it will look fine at 400px and most of the times, the image
                        will be displayed at a smaller size (eg, if two column are being used or viewport is smaller than 1280px).
                        This $_imgSize value could even be decreased further, based on the page layout
                        (one column, two column, three column) and number of product columns. */ ?>
                <?php $_imgSize = 300; ?>
                <img id="product-collection-image-<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"
                     src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->keepFrame(false)->resize($_imgSize); ?>"
                     alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
            </a>
            <?php // Product description ?>
            <div class="product-shop">
                <div class="f-fix">
                    <div class="product-primary">
                        <?php $_productNameStripped = $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true); ?>
                        <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped; ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name'); ?></a></h2>

                        <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product) ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php
                        // Provides extra blocks on which to hang some features for products in the list
                        // Features providing UI elements targeting this block will display directly below the product name
                        if ($this->getChild('name.after')) {
                            $_nameAfterChildren = $this->getChild('name.after')->getSortedChildren();
                            foreach ($_nameAfterChildren as $_nameAfterChildName) {
                                $_nameAfterChild = $this->getChild('name.after')->getChild($_nameAfterChildName);
                                $_nameAfterChild->setProduct($_product);
                                echo $_nameAfterChild->toHtml();
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-secondary">
                        <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-secondary">
                        <?php if(!$_product->canConfigure() && $_product->isSaleable()): ?>

 <div class="qty-wrapper">
            <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>
            <input type="number" pattern="\d*(\.\d+)?" name="qty" id="qty"  maxlength="12" value="1" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')-  >quoteEscape($this->__('Qty')) ?>" class="input-text qty" />
        </div>

     <p class="action"><button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('Add to Cart')) ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button></p>
                        <?php elseif($_product->getStockItem() && $_product->getStockItem()->getIsInStock()): ?>
                            <p class="action"><a title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('View Details')) ?>" class="button" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->__('View Details') ?></a></p>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <p class="action availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <ul class="add-to-links">
                            <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                                <li><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                                <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="desc std">
                        <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped ?>" class="link-learn"><?php echo $this->__('Learn More') ?></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ol>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('products-list', 'none-recursive')</script>

    <?php else: ?>

    <?php // Grid Mode ?>

    <?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
    <?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
    <ul class="products-grid products-grid--max-<?php echo $_columnCount; ?>-col">
        <?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
<?php if($this->getIsHomepage() && $i==4) break; ?>
            <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>

            <li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
                <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">
                    <?php $_imgSize = 210; ?>
                    <img id="product-collection-image-<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"
                         src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize($_imgSize); ?>"
                         alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
                </a>
                <div class="product-info">
                    <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></a></h2>
<div style="border-bottom: 3px solid #f6be30;"></div>
                    <?php
                    // Provides extra blocks on which to hang some features for products in the list
                    // Features providing UI elements targeting this block will display directly below the product name
                    if ($this->getChild('name.after')) {
                        $_nameAfterChildren = $this->getChild('name.after')->getSortedChildren();
                        foreach ($_nameAfterChildren as $_nameAfterChildName) {
                            $_nameAfterChild = $this->getChild('name.after')->getChild($_nameAfterChildName);
                            $_nameAfterChild->setProduct($_product);
                            echo $_nameAfterChild->toHtml();
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                    <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <div class="actions">
                        <?php if(!$_product->canConfigure() && $_product->isSaleable()): ?>
 <div class="qty-wrapper">
            <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>
            <input type="text" pattern="\d*(\.\d+)?" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Qty')) ?>" class="input-text qty" />
        </div>
                            <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('Add to Cart')) ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
                        <?php elseif($_product->getStockItem() && $_product->getStockItem()->getIsInStock()): ?>
                            <a title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('View Details')) ?>" class="button" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->__('View Details') ?></a>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
<?php endif ?>
            <?php /*if ($i%$_columnCount==0 || $i==$_collectionSize): ?>
            <?php endif*/ ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateGeneric($$('ul.products-grid'), ['odd','even','first','last'])</script>
    <?php endif; ?>


</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php
// Provides a block where additional page components may be attached, primarily good for in-page JavaScript
if ($this->getChild('after')) {
    $_afterChildren = $this->getChild('after')->getSortedChildren();
    foreach ($_afterChildren as $_afterChildName) {
        $_afterChild = $this->getChild('after')->getChild($_afterChildName);
        //set product collection on after blocks
        $_afterChild->setProductCollection($_productCollection);
        echo $_afterChild->toHtml();
    }
}
?>
```

To do this which file I need to edit and include any code for the description. Help needed. Thank you in Advance.

Comment: please put coding of phtml file which fetching this products

Comment: I have added the code. Please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code find this code

```
 <div class="product-secondary">
                    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                </div>
```

and change add below things

```
      <div class="product-secondary">
       <div ><?php echo $this->__('Price'); ?> </div>
        <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
      </div> 
      $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
      <div class="description"> <?php echo substr($product->getDescription(), 0, 100) ; ?> </div>
```

Comment: It didn't work. I have cleared caches in magento has well in browser.

Comment: @Ritu check your description attribute is allowd to list page

Comment: @Ritu http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9928/adding-custom-attributes-to-product-list follow this link for description and do reindexing

Comment: yes its allowed to the "Used Product Listing"

Comment: @Ritu do reindexing and check again

Comment: I have done it. Still it doesn't  shows up.

Comment: @Ritu please check again with updated code

Comment: Check your attribute for description . Are they both set to Visible on Product View Page on Front-end = Yes?

Comment: Yes both are set to visible.

Comment: Still that one doesn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50137/discussion-between-ritu-and-murtuza-zabuawala).

Comment: Note I am not using any theme, developing from scratch

Comment: @Ritu update your block code

Comment: How to update the block code. I mean i didn't get u

Comment: @Ritu whats code in this `getLoadedProductCollection` method ,

Comment: public function getLoadedProductCollection()
    {
        return $this->_getProductCollection();
    }

Comment: This is the code what we have in getLoadedProductCollection..

Comment: It is a real performance killer to use `load` in loops. Also your code does not work properly if you have multiple languages. It will always give you the description for the default settings.

Comment: @Marius I know using `load` in even phtml is performance killer, But  if see  my edits then this code doesn't work for her  so at last I give This solution

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId()); ?>
<?php echo $_product->getShortDescription();?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the attribute `description` is marked as 'Used in product listing' `Yes` and the indexes are rebuilt. Then you can just use `$_product->getDescription()` anywhere in the foreach loop.